# Writing to addresses of contiguous memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, fread

Say I have an array allocated of size N, each X bytes long. 
For example, let N = X = 2.

`int *iArray = calloc(N, X)`

So with this call I now have a contiguous array of 4 bytes.

What if I attempt to write to index 0 `(iArray + 0)` a data that is 4 bytes long? Should I expect half of the information to be at index 0 and the other half to be written to index 1? This would, of course, be an error and would likely be caught by the compiler at compile time, but are my expectations correct?

---

I ask because I actually have a similar situation.

I have an array of contiguous elements dynamically allocated as above. The method required to populate this array is a call to:

`fread(void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream)`.

This function is defined to take a pointer to a block of memory with allocated space equal to, or greater than, `count*size` bytes. The file I am reading from is of binary format with integers stored sequentially. Is `fread()` unbiased in the sense that it literally stores `count*size` bytes read in from the file into the memory space pointer to by `ptr`, or are there other things to consider that I am not seeing?

Would a call like:
`fread(ptr, sizeof(int), 99999, FILEptr)`

Be sufficient assuming `ptr` points to a memory block of adequate space?

I am not currently able to test whether this will work, but it seems to make intuitive sense. I also just wanted to clarify my understanding of these topics.

Comment: how can it be caught at compile time when the size of the block is set at run time? Anyway, C does no array bounds checking in general.

Comment: It is just a sequence of bytes.  Fread knows nothing about the intended data type.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of writing to an array of type `int` something that is `> sizeof(int)`.

Comment: All that matters is the total number of bytes in the memory allocated. The type is irrelevant.

Comment: @sherrellbc All comments still apply. You exceed your allocation size, its UB. It really is that simple.

Comment: Perfect. I just wanted to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: There's no difference between `calloc(N, M)` and `malloc(N*M)` (except that `calloc()` also zeroes the memory).

Comment: You can create wrappers around `malloc` and `fread`. In `array_malloc`, create and return a *structure* that stores the array size and a pointer to the raw memory, and check against that in `array_fread`.